# How to quickly count large number of objects with powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to check a synchronization process within two active directory regularly, and to do so I count the objects created in a specific O.U.

There is currently more than 100K objects in the O.U. and it takes more than 10 minutes using either the `myquery | measure` or the `(myquery).count` method.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

**myquery:**

`Get-Recipient -OrganizationalUnit "OUname" -ResultSize Unlimited`

Comment: Well this indicates that `myquery` is maybe not too efficient. Can you show it?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen added to the question

Comment: What kind of synchronization process are you checking? It might be way more efficient to only query for objects that have been modified within the last `x` minutes - like `Get-Recipient -Filter "whenChanged -gt '$((Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5))'" -OrganizationalUnit "OUname" -ResultSize Unlimited`

Comment: tested this, it's still running. The issue is that whatever method we use, it still has to browse all the objects.